# How to stick a div when scrolled past 50% of the item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, sticky

This might be a simple question but please help!
I have implemented a sticky `div` using the code below but I need to know how to change the position at which the `div` gets 'stuck'?

What I want is for my `div` to only get stuck when 50% of it has been scrolled passed the top. At the moment it gets stuck when it reaches the top but I would like 50% of it to keep scrolling to the halfway (roughly) before it gets stuck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#picture1");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        //$("#header_left").html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) { s.addClass("stick"); $("body").css("margin-top", s.height()); } else { s.removeClass("stick"); $("body").css("margin-top", 0); }

    });
});
```

and CSS

```css
.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    /*_top: expression( ie6 = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px") );*/
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `windowpos >= pos.top` to `windowpos >= (s.height()/2) + pos.top`

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/BVK2q/

Comment: Thanks for that but when it gets the that position the whole div disappears!

Comment: i am not sure.. but try removing the second if else statement.. the 'margin-top' style might be interfering

Comment: Yes that seems to be something to do with it but if I remove that line, the top 50% of the sticked Div becomes stuck as the footer(maybe repeating) and the rest of the body jumps to fill the space of the fixed div as if it disappears.  We are on the right track though!

Comment: could you do a fiddle?

Comment: Very like Morven's fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GKC9q/4/ but I need to .stick with only 50% showing rather than it jumping back to 100%

Comment: Yes! Seems to be it...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GKC9q/4/)

The div get's `.stick` style only when your div goes up by 50%. But when you apply `fixed` position to some div, it gets out from the normal layout and you loses the ability to get any margin on themselves. So, you have to apply margin or padding to the body in this case, which you have already done as well.

Anyways, I have just tweak your code a little to show how you can get what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $("#picture1"),
pos = s.position(),
sHeight = s.height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= (sHeight/2) + pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
        $('body').css('paddingTop', sHeight + 60);
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
        $('body').css('paddingTop', '0');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. But how do you make it stick with only the 50% .stick? So it doesnt jump back down to 100% .stick like in your demo